# B2C Custom Policy - How to show the signup links from a Selfasserted DataUri signin page

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, identity-experience-framework

I am using the DataUri: `urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:unifiedssp:2.1.0` for my signin page.
This displays the signup links from the ClaimsProviderSelection.

The issue is that I want to add additional Display claims to the signin and the `unifiedssp` DataUri appears to force only allowing 2 display claims. The second one is always forced to be password even if the data input type is something like a `DropdownSingleSelect`.

[image: Country Code Setup]

[image: Displayclaims on signin]

[image: Sign html]

Any additional display claims are just not shown.

---

I am able to get the signin experience that I want with the `selfasserted` (`urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:selfasserted:2.1.1`) DataUri, but in that situation I have not figured out how to show the signup link.

The Documentation makes a specific comment about the `setting.showSignupLink` meta data only being available on the `unifiedssp` DataUri. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/self-asserted-technical-profile#metadata

**Is there a way to display the signup links from the `ClaimsProviderSelections` on a selfasserted DataUri page? (Or a way to display more inputs on the `unifiedssp`)**

Comment: Jon, Please verify this git hub scenario and it may help (https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/48091). The only way is to embed a link to sign up, which sends the user back to the app and launches a sign up policy. You cannot use the combined page since it forces username/password fields.

Comment: Yes, I think that is a solution that would, but I was certainly hoping for the ability to add the signup link through the custom policies.

Comment: Can I move comments into Answer box?

Comment: Yes, sounds good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Jon, Please verify this git hub scenario (https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/48091). The only way is to embed a link to sign up, which sends the user back to the app and launches a sign up policy. You cannot use the combined page since it forces username/password fields

Comment: It's same for the "ForgetPassword" link, with the `unifiedssp` data uri you can't add custom claims. That means technically, you can't combine the common signin experience with customization at all. 
I suggest to have the link experience for `selfasserted`, too. That would solve a good number of SO questions :-)